# How to convert json respone into php object?

Tags: php, json

Below is my `json` response, I am using `json_decode` for converting the response in `php object`, 'status' and 'msg' is converted successfully but problem is with 'amt'. How to get 'amt' in php object?
`$amt=$response->transaction_details['amt'];` is not working.

### RESPONSE :

{"status":1,"msg":"Transactions Fetched Successfully","transaction_details":{"686868686505":{"payid":"293642892","amt":"10.00","txnid":"686868686505","additional_charges":"0.00","productinfo":"SHIRT","firstname":"WILLIAM}}}

### CODE :

```
$response = json_decode($o,true);
$msg = $response['msg']; 
$status = $response['status'];
$amt=$response->transaction_details->['amt'];
echo '<br>';
echo $amt;
echo '<br>';
echo $msg;
echo '<br>';
echo $status;
```

### OUTPUT :

Transactions Fetched Successfully
1

Comment: Does this work? `$amt=$response->transaction_details['amt'];`

Comment: No, its not working.

Comment: You will have *to iterate* through the key collection (by transaction details) to find the object for the key "x" (eg. "686868686505"). This is no different than *iterating* any PHP array/hash mungeup. Why they generated the JSON like this.. I don't know. It really should have been an array (as you can see the txnid is already part of the inner object). The actual "path" with the given example would be `response["transaction_details"]["686868686505"]["amt"]`, but this *will change* based on the txnid which is why *iteration* of some form (even if it is getting "first element") is required.

Comment: (Also, to answer the question in the title: `json_decode` converts the JSON into a PHP object.. use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or whatever to view the generated PHP object graph.)

Comment: Also From your json string its not valid your missing a " eg: 
"firstname":"WILLIAM}}}
should be "firstname":"WILLIAM"}}}
but its working with $response["transaction_details"]["686868686505"]["amt"]

Comment: after you fixing your JSON (like Luke said), you can access with this code `$amt=$response->transaction_details->{686868686505}->amt;`

Comment: `$amt=$response["transaction_details"]["$txnid"]["amt"];` working for me.thnx @LukeHardiman

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing arrays with object.

`json_decode` second parameter will let you to get json object or json array, it will return json object if it is null or false, and return json array if you set the second parameter to true or anything that translate to true.

see the documentation of it in php.net

that so, you need to change it to:

```
$response = json_decode($o); // or json_decode($o, false);
$msg = $response->msg; 
$status = $response->status;
//since you use all numbers for json property, I'll assume this would fail
$amt=$response->transaction_details->686868686505->amt;
echo '<br>';
echo $amt;
echo '<br>';
echo $msg;
echo '<br>';
echo $status;
```

or if you like using array

```
$response = json_decode($o,true);
$msg = $response['msg']; 
$status = $response['status'];
$amt=$response['transaction_details']['686868686505']['amt'];
echo '<br>';
echo $amt;
echo '<br>';
echo $msg;
echo '<br>';
echo $status;
```